# The unique bounded solution to this recurrence sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

In my paper "Row-Summable matrices with application to
generalization of Schröder’s and Abel’s
Functional equations" I discuss the existence of a bounded solution for some functional equations and especially, for some recurrence sequences. For example, I showed the recurrence relation $$2na_n + (\sin n) a_{n^2}+ (\cos n)a_{n^3} = {1\over n}$$ has  a unique bounded solution $(a_n).$ Is there an idea to obtain such a solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to find the solution, if it is possible.

Comment: Can you indicate a site where this paper is accessible ?

Comment: https://rdcu.be/ctKxv

Comment: By using this link you can access(online) to this paper

Comment: Setting $a_n=\frac{1}{2n^2}+b_n$, one gets an equation without RHS, but is it a simplification ?

Comment: Since $(a_n)$ is bounded, from using the reccurence relation one can get $a_n \rightarrow 0.$